# why Keras fit_generator() load before actually "training"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

sorry to bother:

I am confused by keras function : fit_generator

I use custom generator to generate (image,seg_image)
for training

Look carefully you can see inside of `get_seg()` function

I put the `print(path)` ann the path is just the
path to read image

from data ,the one more intention is I would like to know how

`fit_generator()` get the data from generator

```
#import all the stuff
def get_seg(#parameters ):
    print(path) #to track when this function is called 
    return seg_image     #for training 

#pre-processing image 
def getimage(#parameters):
    #do something to image
    return the imgage      #for training

def data_generator():
#load all the data for training 
    zipped =cycle(zip(images,segmentations))
    while True:
        X = []
        Y = []
        for _ in range(batch_size) :
            im , seg = next(zipped)
            X.append(getimage(#parameters))  
            Y.append(get_seg(#parameters))
    yield np.array(X) , np.array(Y) 

#create an generator 
G = data_generator(#parameters) 
#start training
for ep in range( epochs ):
    m.fit_generator( G , steps_per_epoch=512, 
                     epochs=1,workers=1)
```

While I start training, I get the really unexpected result ,As it goes

through training:The terminal looks like:
it print out 24 set of path

fist which it take the data from custom `data_generator`

```
data/train/0000_mask.png
data/train/0001_mask.png
data/train/0002_mask.png
data/train/0003_mask.png
data/train/0004_mask.png
data/train/0005_mask.png
data/train/0006_mask.png
data/train/0007_mask.png
data/train/0008_mask.png
data/train/0009_mask.png
data/train/0010_mask.png
data/train/0011_mask.png
data/train/0012_mask.png
data/train/0013_mask.png
data/train/0014_mask.png
data/train/0015_mask.png
data/train/0016_mask.png
data/train/0017_mask.png
data/train/0018_mask.png
data/train/0019_mask.png
data/train/0020_mask.png
data/train/0021_mask.png
data/train/0022_mask.png
data/train/0023_mask.png
```

And then :
I do believe the training starts here .

```
1/512 [..............................] - ETA: 2:14:34 - loss: 2.5879 - acc: 0.1697
```

load the data(image) again

```
data/train/0024_mask.png
data/train/0025_mask.png
```

---

After 512(steps_per_epoch) which means the next round training

begins,it would just print next 24 path before training ....

I would like to know why this is happening? Is this is how keras

works? To load data before actually pass is through the network?

Or I am misunderstand or miss something basic knowledge?

Comment: by the way ,the batch_size=2 ,if I set it to 1 it would still print 12 path before training....

Comment: it seems keras always loads 2 more batches than`max_queue_size`. I'm not insure why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is how Keras works.

Training and loading are two parallel actions. One does not see how the other is going.

In the `fit_generator` method there is a `max_queue_size` argument, usually equal to 10 by default. This means the generator will load data at full speed until the queue is full. So you're loading many images in advance (this is good to avoid that the model gets slowed by loading)

And the training just checks: are there items in the queue? Good, train.

You're printing more than your batches because you call `get_seg` inside a loop but only call `yield` outside this loop.

Comment: OK,I feel like i learn something from here,but :


(1) the argument is unspecified, max_queue_size will default to 10. if I set batch_size to 1 it would still print 12 and why is this give 12 ? 


(2) And from your answer :And the training just checks: are there items in the queue? Good, train.
but I think the image get passed are (0024,0025) which both are not inside the queue? 
BIG THANKS!!!!!

Comment: I don't know why the 2 extra. Perhaps keras is slow between training and printing the status of training. The batches 24, 25 are added to the queue after keras trains two other batches from the queue. --> Is there a batch in the queue? Get batch and train // In parallel the generator side will check: is there space in the queue? Load and fill the queue.

Comment: If you use batch size = 1, you will see a lot of prints before the epoch ends. They're being loaded in parallel with the training.

Comment: I think i figure out the second one,the (0024,0025) is just another loading processing? It doesn't mean that 0024 and 0025 are passed into network,right?

Comment: The print happens in "loading" the queue. The network will get these batches when all others in front of the queue are finished.

Comment: This link may  help: https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/tip-fit_generator-in-keras-how-to-parallelise-correctly/

Comment: What if I want to know what are got passed into networks since I would like to check if the shuffle does it's job?

Comment: You can't know. But shuffle doesn't happen with `yield` generators. If you want to shuffle, you have to shuffle yourself inside the generator.

Comment: If you want automatic shuffle, implement a `keras.utils.Sequence` - https://keras.io/utils/

Comment: OK,maybe I sum this whole thing up:
The print is just the load the data ,while when it start training it would take data from queue ?And at the same time the data is still being loaded into queue? Is the whole statement correct?